# PHP & MongoDB = 502 Nginx response and no error log entry

Tags: mongodb, nginx, php

I am having a problem with my PHP process crashing whenever I try to connect to MongoDB from inside PHP.

```
    $options = array(
        'replicaSet' => false,
        'persist' => false,
        'connect' => false,
        'username' => false,
        'password' => false
    );

    $mongo = new \Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017', $options);
```

The following `php-cli` code works fine though:

```
$ php -a
php > $mongo = new \Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');
php > var_dump($mongo);
object(Mongo)#1 (4) {
  ["connected"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["status"]=>
  NULL
  ["server":protected]=>
  string(25) "mongodb://localhost:27017"
  ["persistent":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

However, there is nothing in the PHP error log when this happens (If I throw an exception right before it, *that* exception is logged). However, the FPM and syslogs catch the following entries. It's as if PHP just flips out and crashes before anything can be logged.

```
php5-fpm.log: WARNING: [pool www] child 9261 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
after 57.894803 seconds from start


syslog: localhost kernel: [12191.961070] php5-fpm[9261]: segfault at 8 ip 
00007f5329b1b371 sp 00007fff37343b68 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[7f5329a97000+197000]
```

- PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (API 20090626)
- MongoDB 1.2.10 extension
- Suhosin v0.9.32.1

#### How can I debug what appears to be an actual bug?

### Update:

I just upgraded my OS to ubuntu 12.04 LTS

- PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 (API 20090626)
- MongoDB 1.2.12 extension
- Suhosin v0.9.33

However I still have the problem.

```
syslog: kernel: [ 6727.997940] php5-fpm[9012]: 
segfault at 8 ip 00007f1fdf8cab91 sp 00007fff7f07a4a8 error 4
in libc-2.15.so[7f1fdf842000+1b3000]
```

Comment: 5.3.6 is old and buggy version, you should update it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem lay with Mongo's handling of my `$options` array.

```
$options = array(
    'replicaSet' => false,
    'persist' => false,
    'connect' => false,
    'username' => false,
    'password' => false
);

$mongo = new \Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017', $options);
```

Crashes the process while the following works

```
$options = array(
    'replicaSet' => false,
    'persist' => false,
    'connect' => false,
    //'username' => false,
    //'password' => false
);

$mongo = new \Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017', $options);
```

Basically, don't pass a username or password unless you need too. I guess this really is a bug.

Comment: Yes its a connection issu, try just new Mongo() if you use defaults options. In my case, the problem was the MongoDB server down.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mongo 1.2.11. It seems 1.2.10 has problems with php-fpm.

Comment: Ok, I updated to `MongoDB 1.2.12`, however the problem still exists.